# How to see that diagonal and tranvections matrices generate $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, linear-groups

I'm trying to see how diagonal and transvection matrices generate  $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

Is there any book that I can find a more detailed description of this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to use row/column reduction to reduce a matrix in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ to diagonal form?

Comment: No, Can you introduce me any book to read about that ? I imagine that this reduction is the answer to my question ...

Comment: The case for $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is in any good linear algebra book, and the same works for $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ for any field $\mathbb{F}$. But $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field and so more is needed. For $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ you need a little tiny bit of number theory, for example Euclid's algorithm for obtaining greatest common divisors of a set of integers; this is applied to the set of entries of a row or column of the matrix, whose g.c.d. must equal $1$ in order to be invertible over $\mathbb{Z}$. But I don't know a good book which does this explicitly, perhaps others can chime in.

Comment: I personally do not voice how to show that the Gauss reduction
method to generate any matrix in $Gl_n(\Bbb{Z})$ as a product of
diagonal and triangular matrices in $Gl_n(\Bbb{Z})$. take for
example the matrix $M=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)$.